# sphinx (numpydoc) syntax warnings showing up in wrong file using vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-sphinx, lint, numpydoc

In my `docs/source/conf.py` file, I have the `numpydoc` extension enabled, and it's generally working, except I'm getting docstring errors from different python files showing up as being caused in line 1, column 1 of the `conf.py` file instead of the source file.

Is there anyway to get these warnings to show up on the correct file?

[image]

Comment: To me it looks like the warning is about `holodeck.cosmology.Cosmology.a_to_tage`.

Comment: @mzjn yes.  Which is a different file than `conf.py`, and hence the problem

Comment: The error is from numpydoc validation. See https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation.html. Add a `returns` section to your docstring, and it should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the validation section @StevePiercy, that's a helpful start for me.  The issue I'm having isn't with the warning given by numpydoc, but that the warnings are being associated with `conf.py` instead of the file actually triggering the warning.

Comment: Does it really? What does the warning say?

Comment: @StevePiercy the attached image shows the Warning (RT01) showing up for `docs/source/conf.py`, whereas the warning itself pertains to the separate `Cosmology.py` file.

Comment: Are you asking why your editor makes the association to `conf.py`? Maybe it's an unreported bug? In any case, the warning is clear to me that the docstring in `Cosmology.py` lacks a `returns` section.